# Allure Report does not show Severity levels other than NORMAL for Junit 4 tests

Tags: junit, allure

I am working on a simple JUnit 4 tests where I have integrated Allure to display the test results.

On the test level, I have provided below annotation to display Severity: -

`@Severity(SeverityLevel.CRITICAL)`

But in the Allure report, after generation, it only shows Severity as NORMAL for Severity levels: -

`Severity: normal`

Anyone know what is the possible solution?

I tried updating the test case at runtime using Allure Lifecycle to create custom label but it does not reflect the Allure UI.

```
AllureLifecycle lifecycle = Allure.getLifecycle();
        lifecycle.updateTestCase(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), testResult ->
                testResult.getLabels().add(new Label().setName("severity").setValue(SeverityLevel.CRITICAL.toString())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work for me either. Had to create my own annotation annotated with `@LabelAnnotation(name = SEVERITY_LABEL_NAME)`.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@LabelAnnotation(name = SEVERITY_LABEL_NAME)
public @interface TestSeverity {
    SeverityLevel value();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with bad argLine with maven-surefire-plugin.
In argLine must be:

```
<argLine>
  -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
</argLine>
```

More detail: https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_maven